# Conceptual difficulty in a proof given in I.N Herstein

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

Consider the following theorem given in I.N. Herstein's "Topics in Algebra"

> THEOREM 2.5.1 $\ \ $ If $H$ and $K$ are finite subgroups of $G$ of orders $o(H)$ and $o(K)$, respectively, then $$o(HK)=\frac{o(H)o(K)}{o(H\cap K)}$$

The proof starts by showing how the numerator comes for the trivial case where the intersection of H and K is just identity. This part is clear to me.

Now, for the general case, the book proceeds by saying that for an element $h_1$in $H\cap K$ any element $hk\in HK$ can be written as $hk=(hh_1)(h_1^{-1}k)$ and goes on to say that this product has a multiplicity of at least ${o(H\cap K)}$ and then shows that any repetition besides this is already accounted in the above form.

This proof basically hinges on the fact that $hk=(hh_1)(h_1^{-1}k)$ where $(hh_1)\in H$ and $(h_1^{-1}k)\in K$.

But, $hk=(hh_1)(h_1^{-1}k)$ will *also* be true if $h_1$ were *not* an element of $H\cap K$ but any element that let's say belonged to just $H$ or $K$ since the equality is just an *identity* as

$hk=(hh_1)(h_1^{-1}k)=h(h_1h_1^{-1})k=hek=hk$

Now, one thing that comes to mind for this not to be true is maybe that the product on the RHS loses the structure of the product of $HK$ if $h_1$ is not an element of both H and K.

But I am still not convinced with this (since technically nothing stops me from writing the above product) and looking for an explanation why $h_1$ *has to be* an element of both $H$ and $K$.

Comment: Notice that $h_1 \in H \cap K$ means that $h_1 \in K$.  This means we can "take out" a factor of $h_1$ from any element of $K$ and obtain another element of $K$.  This is not the case if we pick random elements of $G$ that are not elements of $K$.  Symmetrically, since $h_1 \in H$, $hh_1 \in H$, and this is not true for random elements of $G$ that are not elements of $H$.  So to have $hh_1 \in H$ and $h_1^{-1}k \in K$, we require $h_1 \in H \cap K$.  So, as we let $h_1$ wander around $H \cap K$, we find several elements of $HK$ that are equal in $G$ (as you showed).

Comment: The standard proof: Consider the map $f: H\times K\to G: f(h,k)=hk$. Then the number of elements in each equivalence class of this map is $|H\cap K|$ (because $hk=h'k'$ iff $h^{-1}h'=k'k^{-1}=z$, $z\in H\cap K$) hence the result.

Comment: @Eric Towers
I understand the argument you gave. And it is precisely "So to have $hh_1∈H$ and $h^{−1}_1k∈K$, we require $h_1∈H∩K$"  with which I have an issue. Why do we require $hh_1∈H$ and $h^{−1}_1k∈K$ in the first place? The equality would still be true if let's say $h_1$ was *only* part of $H_1$ so that $hh_1∈H$ and $h^{−1}_1k∈K$  doesn't hold.  (wouldn't it?)

Comment: We know that $H$ is closed under multiplication -- so the product of two elements of $H$ gives an element of $H$.  We know $K$ is closed under multiplication -- so the product of two elements of $K$ gives an element of $K$.  We *also* know that the product of an element of $H$ and a non-element of $H$ cannot give an element of $H$. (Cancel the starting element of $H$ with its inverse an observe you have written (not an element of $H$) = (a product of things in $H$), but $H$ is closed under multiplication.)  Likewise an element of $K$ times a non-element of $K$ cannot be in $K$.

Comment: @Eric Towers if $h_1$ was in H *only* then $h_1^{-1}$ is in H only such that $h_1^{-1}k$ is *not* in K. Is this what you are saying? If yes. I understand this point. But then why $h_1^{-1}k$ *has to be* in K for the equality to hold. It still holds without this ryt? Or would the definition of HK not make sense then?

Comment: $h_1$ has to be in $H \cap K$ so that it is simultaneously in $H$ and $K$.  That is, $hh_1$ is in $H$ and $h_1^{-1}k$ is in $K$.  This means we are finding elements of $HK$ that have the same value in $G$.  If you do not pick $h_1 \in H \cap K$, you do not have $h h_1 \in H$, $h_1^{-1}k \in K$, so $(h h_1)(h_1^{-1}k) \in HK$.

Comment: An example might help.  Let $G$ be the integers, $H$ be the even integers, $K$ be the multiples of $3$, and the operation be addition.  A generic element of $HK$ is $2+3$.  $H \cap K$ is multiples of $6$.  Say we want to carve off some of the element of $K$ and put what is removed into the element of $H$ so that starting and ending, we have an element of $HK$.  Then we can't carve off random integers because we won't ensure that modified $3$ is still an element of $K$.  We also can't just carve off, for example, $3$, because $2+3 \not \in H$.  (cont...)

Comment: We have to carve off something that is both a multiple of $3$ (so the element of $K$ becomes an element of $K$) and a multiple of $2$ (so the element of $H$ becomes an element of $H$).  But this means we only get to carve off an element of $H \cap K$, the multiples of $6$.  When we do this, we get several elements of $HK$ that are actually the same element of $G$: $\dots$, $(2+12)+(3-12)$, $(2+6)+(3-6)$, $(2+0)+(3-0)$, $(2-6)+(3+6)$, $(2-12) + (2+12)$, $\dots$.  And so we find out $|H| |K|$ overcounts $|G|$ by a factor of $|H \cap K|$, which is the size of $G$-equal elements of $HK$.